# Refresh a form with Ajax after closing a Dialog

Tags: forms, ajax, 9, modal-dialogs

So I have a custom form in which I display a list of entities.
Below that list, I added an “Add More” link which opens a Dialog.
When I close (or submit) the Dialog, I want the list of entities to be updated dynamically without refresh.

[image]

I looked but I can't find a way to add a Dialog callback function. So I added an "update" button in my custom form with an ajax callback to refresh the form. Then, in a javascript file, I trigger the update button when the event 'dialog:afterclose' occures.

```
  Drupal.behaviors.addFriend_modalcallback = {
    attach: function () {

      $(window).once('addfriend-modalcallback').on('dialog:afterclose', function (e) {

        $('input[data-drupal-selector="edit-update"]').trigger('mousedown');

      });

    }
  };
```

This is obviously a messy solution. Do you guys know a clean way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: While this might be messy, but it's the only solution I know about, apart from reloading the page, which brings other issues.